# Namespace issue with Jax-Ws webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, xml-namespaces, jax-ws-customization

I have a scenario where I have written webserive in Jax-Ws, from this webservice I am calling third party webservice developed in axis.

I am facing namespace issue, JAX-WS by default add namespace attribute in each of the request, where as axis webservice does not take namespace.

Is there a way by which I can remove namespace from SOAP request, before passing it to axis webservice. I tried writing handler and removing namespace from SOAP request however that doesn't seems to be feasible solution.

Comment: Please provide any usable information necessary to answer your question.

Comment: Request SOAP <soapenv:Body>
<ns2:standardizeAddress xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/cadsAddressStandardization/">                    Response from axis webservice <standardizeAddressResponse xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="cadsAddressStandard.xsd">

Comment: What do you mind to be feasible solution?